# How to get array value by key

Tags: php, arrays

I am having an strange issue while transversing array, created by html input.
Here is my html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="new_date['rule'][]" value="hfgfgfgfg">
<input type="date" name="new_date['date'][]" />
```

if I submit form then I get array like this:

```
$var=$_POST['new_date'];
echo"<pre>";
print_r($var);
echo"</pre>";
//output
Array
(
    ['rule'] => Array
        (
            [0] => rule_5a6c50ff02fff
        )

    ['date'] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2018-05-24
        )

)
```

if I am trying the array with key `rule` then I am getting nothing or empty.

```
print_r($var['rule']);
//output
.....empty......
```

Please help. TIA

Comment: try with `$var["'rule'"]`

Comment: yes, its working @ChetanAmeta... Thank you... please make it answer I will accept it as answer :)

Comment: thanks :), I put my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HTML you have `used new_date['rule'][]` which have key as `'rule'` so while retriving through POST you need to use same key i.e. with single quote

USE below:

```
var_dump($var["'rule'"])
```

To use : `$var['rule']` you may need to use `new_date[rule][]` in your html

Answer (score 4):

You can try this

```
<input type="hidden" name="new_date[rule][]" value="hfgfgfgfg">
<input type="date" name="new_date[date][]" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
echo $var["'rule'"][0];
```

This is because you are using

```
name="new_date['rule'][]"
```

in HTML. Instead you should use

```
name="new_date[rule][]"
```

Hopefully, this will solve your problem

If you var_dump() $var, this will be the output:

```
array(2) {
  ["'rule'"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "hfgfgfgfg"
  }
  ["'date'"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2018-05-11"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try using `$var["'rule'"]`